# What are essential minerals to added to water which is filtered through Reverse Osmosis, when to be added whether after or before Ozonisation

Tags: water

Sir,

I want information with reference to the subject cited above.
What are the essential minerals to be added to water after purification and Reverse osmosis?

When are the minerals to be added -after or before Ozonisation?

What are the methods and procedure and name of chemical/natural compounds which carry the essential minerals are to be added?

Thanking you very much.

Yours sincerely, MVprasad

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by essential minerals? Are you specifically thinking of brewing here? What is your goal/what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is what minerals you need to keep your yeast healthy then: "minerals such as potassium, iron, copper, zinc, phosphorous, magnesium, and calcium."[[1]](https://byo.com/stories/item/950-keeping-your-yeast-healthy)

The easiest way to add the nutrients needed for the yeast is to add a special mix that you can buy from any homebrew shop such as [Wyeast Nutrient Blend](https://www.wyeastlab.com/hb_productdetail.cfm?ProductID=15)

Find your local shop and ask for yeast nutrient is my advice.